# Material-UI Tabs: Change active tab text color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following object:

```
const tabStyle = {
    default_tab:{
        color: '#68C222',
        width: '33.3%',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 15
    },
    active_tab:{
        color: grey700,
        width: '33.3%',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 15
    }
};
```

When a tab is clicked, I want to be able to use the active_tab settings. Basically I want it to use the same color for the Tab text as I have for the background color of the `inkBarStyle` (color of the selected tab indicator) below.

```
<Tabs tabItemContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', width: '30%'}} inkBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#68C222', width: '33.3%'}} >
                <Tab style={tabStyle.active_tab} label='Tab1' >
                </Tab>
                <Tab style={tabStyle.default_tab} label='Tab2' >
                </Tab>
                <Tab style={tabStyle.default_tab} label='Tab3' >
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
```

There is an `onChange` property on `Tabs` and `onActive` property on `Tab` that I may be able to use, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your active tab index in state in the `onChange` event handler for `<Tabs />`. Then, for your `<Tab />` component, you can do a conditional in the `style` prop:

```
handleTabChange (index) {
    this.setState({
        activeIndex: index
    });
}

getStyle (isActive) {
    return isActive ? tabStyle.active_tab : tabStyle.default_tab
}

render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;
    return (
        <Tabs onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
            <Tab style={ this.getStyle(activeIndex === 1) } label='Tab1' ></Tab>
            <Tab style={ this.getStyle(activeIndex === 2) } label='Tab2' ></Tab>
            <Tab style={ this.getStyle(activeIndex === 3) } label='Tab3' ></Tab>
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```

Comment: Getting the following error: `Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.` Likely do to the fact that we are calling that function in style. EDIT: fixed my issues. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with a simple conditional statement

```
 <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
   <LinkTab style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: value === 0 ? "bold" : "" }} ... />
   <LinkTab style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: value === 1 ? "bold" : "" }} ... />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your component is not a class component yet, you have to upgrade it because you need to keep a state.

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
             clickedTabs: []
        }
}
```

Do a method which will update the state when a tab is click

```
onTabClick = tagLabel => { 
      this.setState((prevState, tagLabel) => {
          return prevState.tagLabel.push[tagLabel};
      });
  }
```

Then your render `Tab`

```
render() {
return (
      <Tab 
         style={this.state.clickedTabs.find('Tab1') ? 
             'tabStyle.active_tab' : 
             'tabStyle.default_tab' } 
         onClick={this.onTabClick('Tab1')}
         label='Tab1' /> 
  );
}
```